# Potential tradeoffs of this use case between Cassandra and Couchbase

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, couchbase

We currently have a very write-heavy web analytics application which collects a large number of real time events from a large number of websites and stores for subsequent analytics and reporting.

Our initial planned architecture involved a cluster of web servers handling requests, and writing all of the data into a Cassandra cluster, while simultaneously updating a large number of counters for real-time aggregated reports. We also plan to utilize hadoop directly on CassandraFS (as a replacement of HDFS - offered by datastax) to natively run Map Reduce jobs on the data residing in Cassandra for more involved analytics. The output of the MapR jobs would be written back onto ColumnFamilies in Cassandra natively. 
Hadoop map reduce runs on a read-only replica of the main cassandra cluster which is write-heavy. The idea was to avoid multiple data hops and have all data for the analytics in  one repository.

More recently we hear about, and have faced first hand issues managing and growing a cassandra cluster with frequent node outages and bad response times. Couchbase seems to be much better with response times and dynamically growing and managing the cluster. So we are considering replacing Cassandra with Couchbase.

However this brings up a few questions.

1. Does Couchbase scale well in a mostly sequential write-heavy scenario? I don't see our scenario making much use of the in-memory caching, as the raw data being written is rarely read back, only aggregated metrics are. Plus I haven't been able to read much about what happens when Couchbase needs to hit the disk to write back data very frequently (or all the time?). Will it end up performing poorly than Cassandra?
2. What happens to the Hadoop interface? Couchbase has its own map reduce capabilities, but I understand that they are limited in scope. Would I need to transfer data back and forth between CouchbaseDB and HDFS to be able to support all my analytics and reporting out of a single database?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently evaluated Cassandra and Couchbase among other options for a client requirement, so I can shed some light on both datastores.

Couchbase is *incredibly* easy to manage and once you have installed the server on a node, you can manage the cluster completely from the dashboard. However, couchbase does not scale as well as Cassandra, when as the data size grows. I also did not find a way to integrate Couchbase and HDFS/Hadoop seemlessly.

Cassandra performs very well for super fast write throughput, but it does not have any server side aggregation capabilities. Cluster management is slightly more difficult than Couchbase, as you have to re-balance the cluster every time you add or remove a node. Apart from it, from performance standpoint, Cassandra is runs pretty much seamlessly, as long as you have designed the schema properly.

If you can afford Datastax Enterprise solutions for Hive to do map-reduce for sophisticated analytics, I'd recommend you to stay with Cassandra, as couchbase map-reduce support is not all that good, and benchmarks show Couchbase performance starts to detoriate as the cluster size grows.